# Why does Garmin's GDL90 binary protocol go to lengths to avoid using the bookend magic byte in the payload?

Tags: embedded, protocols

I was implementing a parser for [GDL90](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/technology/adsb/Archival/media/GDL90_Public_ICD_RevA.PDF), a UART-based protocol used by some Garmin aviation products, when I came across the following:

> Binary transparency is provided by use of the "byte-stuffing" technique. To include a data byte that coincides with either a Flag Byte (0x7E) or Control-Escape character (0x7D) within a message, each is converted into a unique two-byte sequence.
>
> To prepare a message for transmission, wherever a 0x7D or 0x7E byte is found in between the two Flag Bytes, a Control-Escape character is inserted, followed by the original byte XOR’ed with the value 0x20. Using this method, the Control-Escape and Flag Byte characters only appear in a message for framing or byte-stuffing purposes.
>
> On reception, any Control-Escape characters found are discarded, and the following byte is included in the message after being converted to its original form by XOR’ing with the value 0x20.
>
> For example:
>
> - start of message ID #2 with second byte `0x7E`: `0x7E 0x02 0x7D 0x5E …`
> - start of message ID #3 with second byte `0x7D`: `0x7E 0x03 0x7D 0x5D …`
> - end of message with CRC value of `0x7D 0x7E`: `…0x7D 0x5D 0x7D 0x5E 0x7E`

This was a bit of a head scratcher to me, as anytime I've done binary protocols in the past I use a magic byte to indicate the beginning of the packet, and then if I don't get the CRC and end byte exactly where they're predicted to be, then I throw out the whole packet. So it's never a problem if a magic byte shows up mid-stream, because a magic byte doesn't necessarily mean a packet start/end. GDL90 is different, as Garmin went to such great lengths to avoid using `0x7D` or `0x7E` in the random binary data.

I'm really curious why. While it might make it easy to find the beginning and the ending of packets, it makes it impossible to make guarantees about packet size and transmission time, as a packet which has a lot of `0x7E` could grow substantially. And the advantage of being able to specially find the beginning and end isn't that valuable, as any good parser would throw out any message where the payload length, and the CRC, and the packet end magic byte don't perfectly align. So I don't see any extra advantages, but I do see extra burden.

I don't like to assume that I'm smarter than Garmin's engineers, so I assume they must have had a good reason to make things awkward. Ergo, there's a lesson to be learned here.

*What are the benefits of avoiding the packet bookend byte at all costs?*

---

P.S. This might be asked in the wrong SE. I'm unsure if it's for SE.aviation, SE.softwareengineering, SE.engineering, etc... If SO is the wrong place, feel free to close and point me in the right direction.

Comment: Speculation, but if this byte-stream is being processed by something like an FPGA, it can't wait until the CRC is wrong to figure something out. It needs _hard_ knowledge about what each byte is. Do you have a better way to escape these characters that would be as robust?

Comment: @pmacfarlane that's an interesting comment. I can see some of what you're getting at, but isn't there generally/always a requirement to wait until the CRC before acting on any of the message? And wouldn't the FPGA have hard knowledge that every byte is a data byte, except when it's reset back to the beginning of the parser finite state machine, or it has read `payload length` number of bytes?

Comment: I know nothing about this protocol. But if there are framing bytes that can also be present in the data, you need to be able to escape them. If not, it seems to be impossible to tell which ones are framing and which are data.

Comment: @pmacfarlane I have written a number of binary parsers and marshallers, and the approach I have always taken is that, unless my FSM is awaiting a magic byte indicating framing data for a new message, then the FSM interprets all data as valid bytes for the payload. Could you go some more into why for an FPGA it could be essential to perpetually differentiate between a framing data byte and a normal data byte?

Comment: FPGA was an example. It's better to know your current state at all times, not wait until X characters later then see that you were wrong. Give me a system that does not escape framing characters and I will find an example that breaks it.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Here's an example parser: https://github.com/TauLabs/TauLabs/blob/d0512149b454894ae0cf98c177afc1fb6a68f806/flight/Modules/GPS/UBX.c. It parses GPS data in the UBX format, which is maintained by uBlox (one of the world's largest manufacturers of GPS modules). You can see in the FSM (starting on L65) that we always (think we) know what state we're in. The parser has worked flawlessly across the years, but that doesn't mean it doesn't have hidden weaknesses.

Comment: UBX format here: https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/GPS/Modules/u-blox5_Protocol_Specifications(GPS.G5-X-07036).pdf. Marshalling is on pg. 60.

Answer (score 1):

This protocol is (or is very similar to) [HDLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Data_Link_Control) with asynchronous framing.  The frame delimiter byte (0x7E) allows a low-level serial driver to identify a complete frame without knowing or interpreting anything within the message.  The frame driver can be a simple state machine that:

1. Starts receiving a frame when the frame delimiter is read,
2. Reads frame bytes (and performs byte de-stuffing) while between delimiters,
3. Ends the frame and performs the frame-check-sequence when the frame delimiter is read.
4. If the frame-check-sequence passes then pass the valid frame up to a higher level, where the message will be interpreted.

This framing scheme provides very loose coupling between the frame and the message.  You don't need to include the message length within the frame.  And you don't need to have message types with fixed message lengths.  The length of each message can vary (even messages of the same type can vary in length).  In fact, you could change the message protocol completely without making any changes to the frame driver.

This framing scheme also provides for quick recovery from lost bytes (due to disconnections or whatever).  The receiver will discard the frame it was working on and restart a new frame when any delimiter byte is received.

Your binary protocol requires the receiver's low-level driver to peek into the message to interpret either the message length or the message type so that it can know when to expect the end of the message.  This is tight coupling between your frame driver and your message protocol.

Also, your binary protocol doesn't allow the receiver to recover from a lost byte as quickly.  For example, if a byte is lost, your protocol will continue to read the expected number of bytes and won't recognize the next magic byte as the start of a new frame.  And then there is the potential for your receiver to remain out of sync with the start of a frame for as long as the incoming frames contain magic bytes within the message data.